# Quiero desde un edit text comparar con un String

Tags: string, condiciones, edittext

Intente ingresar un valor en un edit Text y desde ese valor compararlo con un String para ingresar a otra Activity pero no logro conseguir que se ejecute la condicion, aqui les dejo la parte del codigo

```
public void lanzarActivity2(View view){

       String cod = et1.getText().toString();  
        if(cod.equals("raton")){  
            Intent i = new Intent(this, SegundoActivity.class);  
            startActivity(i);  
        } else {  
            Toast.makeText(this, "Codigo Incorrecto",  
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
        }  
    }
```

Comment: ¿Cual es el problema? Te devuelve error o la condición siempre te devuelve false?

Comment: Me devuelve error, al momento de correr el programa y hacer la comparación se cierra la app

Comment: En ningún caso me esta fallando muestra el código completo y el error que te aparece ya que el error estará en otro lado.

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que sea porque el valor cod en algún momento sea null con este ejemplo de no debería dar problemas la aplicación:

```
public void lanzarActivity2(View view){

       String cod = et1.getText().toString();  
        if(("raton").equals(cod)){  
            Intent i = new Intent(this, SegundoActivity.class);  
            startActivity(i);  
        } else {  
            Toast.makeText(this, "Codigo Incorrecto",  
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
        }  
    }
```

Comment: me marca error de tipos incompatibles en el ("raton").

Answer (score 0):

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private  EditText et1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void lanzarActivity2(View view){
    String cod = et1.getText().toString();
    if(cod.equals("raton")){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, SegundoActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Codigo Incorrecto",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public void lanzarAcercaDe(View view){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, AcercaDeActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

public void salir(View v) {
    finish();
}
```

}

Este es el codigo completo, el problema no esta en el codigo, si no en la aplciación